# How to stream video in MJPEG Formate in Mac

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, mjpeg

How can i stream video in MJPEG format in MAC. I am using Qt-kit API of QuickTime.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a motion jpeg that can be viewed with a web browser?

You can try using a WebView. Create an NSURLRequest with the location of the mjpeg and load it in the WebView.